# How can white mate black in 4 moves?

Tags: analysis, endgame, checkmate

In this endgame position, how can black be mated in 4 moves? Being a beginner, I am finding it difficult

```
[FEN "8/8/6R1/8/8/4K2p/7k/8 w - - 0 1"]
```

Comment: Please check online tablebase.

Answer (score 6):

Use the king to keep the black king in the corner and force Black into zugzwang:

```
[FEN "8/8/6R1/8/8/4K2p/7k/8 w - - 0 1"]

1.Kf2 Kh1 2. Re6 Kh2 (2... h2 3. Re1) 3. Rh6 Kh1 4.Rxh3
```

Comment: There's something wrong with my FEN string but I can't figure it out (am on mobile).

Comment: I think you missed a line.

Comment: Great. It was mazing to learn a new technique.thanks

Comment: @Rafiq you're welcome. You can 'accept' this answer by clicking the checkmark next to it.